# android cannot find symbol error

Tags: android

```
Heres my code

package ${YYAndroidPackageName};

import android.util.Log;
import java.lang.String;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

import com.yoyogames.runner.RunnerJNILib;
import ${YYAndroidPackageName}.R;
import ${YYAndroidPackageName}.RunnerActivity;


public class fglads extends BroadcastReceiver
{

public void showads ()
   {

 sendBroadcast(
  new Intent("com.fgl.INVOKE").putExtra("command", "showAd")
    );

  }
```

}

I am getting cannot find symbol error when trying to compile my android game. I dont know much about java

Can any1 tell me whats wrong

Comment: what is thia ${YYAndroidPackageName}.R;

Comment: Game is created using gamemaker and i need to use that code for creating extensions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error code, do you have any xml layout files that go with the java file? if so right click your extension in gamemaker, select open extension directory, then open your extension folder, and open the AndroidSource folder (in my case GM:S had put the xml layout files here, which is incorrect) so you need to create a folder called res inside the AndroidSource folder, open it, and create another folder called layout, then put your xml layout files in here (leave your java file in the AndroidSource folder) hope that helps